# Prevent Rsyslog from removing automatically syslog.gz files.

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Why ubuntu remove older syslog older than syslog.7.gz by default? How can I prevent that to happen? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each package adds a file to `/etc/logrotate.d/`, that way `logrotate` knows when to remove or refresh log files for that package.

`distcc`, for example:

```
$ dpkg -L distcc | fgrep logrotate
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.d/distcc
```

So `/etc/logrotate.d/distcc` contains the rules that `logrotate` will use.

You need to read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for `logrotate`.

`rsyslog` doesn't do anything to rotate or remove log files.